# Cannot open include file: 'ntddk.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, driver

I am getting this error when I am trying to build my driver:

Driver.cpp(7): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ntddk.h': No such file or directory

I am using Visual Studio 2012 with WDK 8.1 installed (I have not cinfigured anything in VS).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Go to project properties -> C/C++ -> General, and add ddk headers path to  Additional Include Directories tab. It should be sth like $(WDKPATH)\inc\ddk where $(WDKPATH) is ofc a directory where You have installed WDK.

Answer (score 2):

You need Visual Studio 2013 for WDK 8.1

[Quote](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg454513.aspx) :

> Important: Before installing WDK 8.1 Update, you need to install
>   Visual Studio 2013. See the Visual Studio links on this page.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and I had the same issue when trying to compile a driver.

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40528971) help me:
You need to add WDK headers path to your vcxproj include directories:
*vcxproj properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories*

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.14393.0\km\
```